# filter 'ng-repeat' based on URL parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wanna filter a ng-repeat based on a parameter from the URL

Say this is the URL-

```
http://sitename/pagename.aspx?Id=27
```

So here I wanna filter on the Id.
like-

```
ng-repeat="oneItem in listOfItems | filter : 27"
```

So the number 27 is to be got dynamically from the URL

Help me out with this guys, Lemme know if you need more info.. :)

Comment: if you are using `ui-router`, `$state.current.url` will return the current url. From that you can take value of `id` and store that in a variable and use that

Comment: are you using `ng-router` or `ui-router`?

Comment: No I'm not ..I'm new to AngularJs and not aware of the complete functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are not using `ng-router` and `ui-router`.

It is a bad practice to filter things in the frontend. Rather, you should send that `ID` to your backend and return the correct result. Then, you could simply do:

```
 ng-repeat="oneItem in listOfItems"
```

You can do this by changing the method that returns a result which then assigned to `listOfItems`.

You can get the ID from url like this:

```
var url = window.location.href;
$scope.productId = url.split("=")[1]  // this assumes that url is exactly like you wrote
```

Then, add this to your `$http` get request and get the data from your backend.

If you still insist on doing it in the front end, do this:

```
ng-repeat="oneItem in listOfItems | filter : {id: productId}"  // this assumes that oneItem object has property of id
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This works for me this time :D:D..Thanks bro..But I'll make sure i get to know about ng-router and ui-router ...(y)